# Accepting changes in Track changes package

Tags: trackchanges

Am using `Track Changes` package in my latex document. Got the package from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/trackchanges/)

To use this package `\usepackage{trackchanges}` and 
Latex document will be `Robinson, \change[ym]{new}{old}, \add[novi]{Thing 1 \& Thing 2, }\add[ym]{Humpty Dumpty}`

To accept all the changes `\usepackage[finalnew]{trackchanges}`.
Accepting changes will be reflected only in PDF output.

Now my question is, Is there any way to remove all the track changes tags in latex document too?

**Expectation:**  Accepting changes in both PDF output and in latex document(i.e.without track change tags(\add or \change etc..))

Latex document should be like `Robinson, new, Thing 1 \& Thing 2, Humpty Dumpty`

Comment: Then how to remove all the `track changes` tags from the latex document

Comment: http://sourceforge.net/projects/trackchanges/

Comment: Please add the link to the question.

Comment: I have added to my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a python program called `acceptchanges.py` in `Track Changes` package itself.  I executed `python acceptchanges.py --infile=input.tex --outfile=output.tex -c` in the command line and got the latex document without the Track changes tags.